# Eclipse - how do I create a source folder from a sub folder without making eclipse look for the wrong package names?

Tags: java, eclipse

I do have a folder structure given such as:
task --> task related non-source stuff, src --> (package1 --> classes), (package 2--classes)

Now whenever I add task/src to the build path, Eclipse always gives me errors for the packages - it keeps saying it wants src.package1 instead of just package1. I suppose that is because it interprets task as the basefolder and src already as the first package - how do I get Eclipse to understand that src is NOT a package?

I am using Eclipse Indigo, and I am not allowed to change the folder structure. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to do the same - I created the following folder structure (at first none of them were source folders):

lib
 - ab

Then opened the Build properties, and added lib/ab as a source folder. Then I created an ABC.java in the ab package in the lib/ab source folder and it worked (in Eclipse Indigo, and I am reasonably sure that it worked before as well).

Comment: Tried that... strangely enough it works for all but one .java file, in which it now says that it expects package "" instead of package package1. Weird. 

Well, thanks anyways cause that mostly fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple source folders on your build path. Therefore I would recommend to delete `src` from the build path and instead add `src/package1/classes` and `src/package2/classes`.

Note that the compiled classes will go as before in the `bin` folder now for both packages.